# Is it a good practice to add object instance attributes according to some condition?

Tags: python, pycharm, factory-method

I have the following python code, where I create a food object, which adds instance attributes according to the food type:

```
class Food:  
      def __init__(self, type):
            self.type=type
            if type=="milk":
                self.__add_milk_attributes()
            else:
                self.__add_apple_attributes()
       
      def ___add_milk_attributes():
          self.liters= 2
          self.fat_precentage=1
          # more attributes of milk

      def ___add_apple_attributes():
          self.wight= 1
          self.color="red"
          # more attributes of apple
```

Is it a good practice to add dynamic attributes as above? I know that Pycharm returns weak warnings that all field should be initiated in the constructor.

Edit: The user cannot accesses the internal object implementation (i.e., Apple or Milk), and should only access the Food constructor to create the object. Thus, inheritance alone is not enough. Is there a way to call the Apple/Milk constructor from the Food contractor, without creating a new object?

Comment: Some people may complain that it's difficult to test the possible permutations when you do this. One fork is probably maintainable. Two could be a real headache, etc.

Comment: Also, the type() built-in method is now gone in your constructor. Not your question, but I would recommend using def __init__(self, _type) instead.

Comment: This is probably better solved with inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view this kind of problems must be solved with inheritance, so you should have three different classes.

A "base class" that is Food:

```
class Food:  
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type
```

Then, another class for Milk:

```
class Milk(Food):
    def __init__(self, type, liters, fat_precentage):
        super().__init__(type)
        self.liters = liters
        self.fat_precentage = fat_precentage
```

And another one for Apple:

```
class Apple(Food):
    def __init__(self, type, wight, color):
        super().__init__(type)
        self.wight = wight
        self.color = color
```

This approach allows you to have more flexible code for any future changes (for example think if you need to add another 10 foods). Then, I think it is also more readable and debuggable

Comment: Edit: The user cannot accesses the internal object implementation (i.e., Apple or Milk), and should only access the Food constructor to create the object. Thus, inheritance alone is not enough. Is there a way to call the Apple/Milk constructor from the Food contractor, without creating a new object?